# symmetric distribution around zero

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

I have a probability distribution function as following, in my simulations, when I plot f(x) versus x, it is symmetric around zero, but I can't prove it mathematically, can anybody help?

\begin{equation}
f(x)= (1/2\pi)  \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}    \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2(\theta^2+1)}}  e^{-\frac{\theta^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{\theta^2+1}}               d\theta
\end{equation}

actually assume that $x=h\theta+n$ where $h,\theta,n$ all have Gaussian distribution, i.e $h \sim N(1,1), ~~\theta \sim N(0,1), ~~n \sim N(0,1)$, so

\begin{equation}
f(x)=   \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x|\theta) f(\theta)                  d\theta
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute $t=-θ$
$$\begin{equation}
f(x)= (1/2\pi)  \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}    \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2(\theta^2+1)}}  e^{\frac{\theta^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{\theta^2+1}}               d\theta \\= 
 (1/2\pi)  \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}    \frac{e^{-\frac{(x+t)^2}{2(t^2+1)}}  e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{t^2+1}}               dt= \\
 (1/2\pi)  \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}    \frac{e^{-\frac{(-x-t)^2}{2(t^2+1)}}  e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{t^2+1}}               dt=f(-x)
\end{equation}$$